# create dynamic factory within a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically create some angular services (I am using js-data as a orm, and want to be able to register models dynamically)

I must be missing something fundamental, as this code does work, when I expected it would ;)

```
angular.module('myApp',['ui.router','ngResource', 'js-data'])

angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('storeService', storeService)

/** @ngInject */
function storeService($injector) {

    // "dynamically" create a new factory
    angular.module('myApp').factory("foobar2", function() {
        return function() {
            return "foobar2";
        }
    });

    console.log($injector.get('foobar2'));        
}
```

so at this point I get an error

"angular.js:13550 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: foobar2Provider <- foobar2"

what gives ? does .factory not create the service immediately ?

this is a simplified version of what I was attempting to do - the actual code would be a parametrized call, rather than hard-coded as it is now. However, this simplified version highlights my misunderstandings well ;)

**update #1**

if I move the foobar2 factory outside the storeService, so the code now looks like this ..

```
angular.module('myApp',['ui.router','ngResource', 'js-data'])

// "dynamically" create a new factory
angular.module('myApp').factory("foobar2", function() {
    return function() {
        return "foobar2";
    }
});

angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('storeService', storeService)

/** @ngInject */
function storeService($injector) {

    console.log($injector.get('foobar2'));        
}
```

then everything works fine - so it must be because the creation of the foobar2 factory is occurring within the storeService.

Am I just hitting a "race" condition where the factory has not yet been setup before I'm calling the $injector ?

**update #2**

I've created a fiddle showing the "problem"

https://jsfiddle.net/j1j9uctd/

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic factory on demand?

Comment: As I said, I'm using js-data to create models based on user data (so I don't know up front the names of these services) and I have a generic data aggregator / ui generator that uses $injector to get to these services